# Android UI component

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello can you tell me how can I add the rectangular box in the android layout which adds up like a 3d effect as in the below screenshot. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add this effect to almost every view or widget, using android:elevation attribute, or programmatically using setElevation(x) method. X is number of Dp. 
Note: This only works on api level 21 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

you are referring to [material design](https://material.io/guidelines/#) you can add this effect using [card view](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView)

Answer (score 0):

Add elevation to your view 
read this documentation for assigning elevation to your view
https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency compile `'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey_300"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```